# How to add draging slider same as Netflix?

Tags: html, css, slider

what i want is to add a dragging slider (or sliding of images by click n swiping ) into my page
Here is the example of code
https://codepen.io/amar1203/pen/ExjyKLz

```
   <html>
   <body>

  https://codepen.io/amar1203/pen/ExjyKLz

    </html
```

but i want dragging feature inisde it check this and help me out with the code.

Comment: Have you tried adding your code on the existing codepen?

Comment: @KK Bro i just updated the link now i tried my code there you can check it . all i need is slick slider for those . can you help me with the code.

Comment: Try slick slider or owl carousel :)

Comment: @AkhilAravind bro i am trying slick sliders but they are mostly written in jquery and i am not that comfortable with it yet. if you can help me out proper jquery code for this . then it will be helpful

Comment: bro, take a look at https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/ , let me know which one you want to implement, I willhelp

Comment: @AkhilAravind bro i wnat that  multiple Items slider can you see it there.. that will be fine

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Check the implementation with slick slider. For more details and implementation options on slick slider, please refer [Here](https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/)

```js
var $ = jQuery;
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('.wrapper').slick({
    infinite: true,
    slidesToShow: 3,
    slidesToScroll: 3,
    mobileFirst:true,
     responsive: [
     {
      breakpoint: 1300,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 5,
        slidesToScroll: 5,
        infinite: true,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 1024,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 3,
        slidesToScroll: 3,
        infinite: true,
      }
    },
    {
      breakpoint: 600,
      settings: {
        slidesToShow: 2,
        slidesToScroll: 2
      }
    }]
  });
});
```

```css
html {
  scroll-behavior: smooth;
}

body {
  margin: 0;
  background-color: #000;
}

h1 {
  font-family: Arial;
  color: red;
  text-align: center;
}

.slick-prev {
  z-index: 1!important;
  left: 0 !important;
}

.slick-prev:before {
  content: '‹' !important;
  font-size: 60px!important;
}

.slick-next {
  right: 0 !important;
}

.slick-next:before {
  content: '›'!important;
  font-size: 60px!important;
}

.item {
  transition: .5s;
}

.item:hover {
  transition: .5s;
  transform: scale(1.2);
}

/* .wrapper {
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 100%);
    overflow: hidden;
    scroll-behavior: smooth;
 }
 .wrapper section {
    width: 100%;
    position: relative;
    display: grid;
    grid-template-columns: repeat(7, auto);
    margin: 20px 0;
 }
 
 .wrapper section .item {
    padding: 0 2px;
    transition: 250ms all;
 }
 .wrapper section .item:hover {
    margin: 0 40px;
    transform: scale(1.2);
 }
 .wrapper section a {
    position: absolute;
    color: #fff;
    text-decoration: none;
    font-size: 6em;
    background: #000;
    width: 80px;
    padding: 20px;
    text-align: center;
    z-index: 1;
 }
 .wrapper section a:nth-of-type(1) {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    left: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(-90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
 }
 .wrapper section a:nth-of-type(2) {
    top: 0;
    bottom: 0;
    right: 0;
    background: linear-gradient(90deg, rgba(0, 0, 0, 0) 0%, rgba(0, 0, 0, 1) 100%);
 } */
```

```html
<link href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.0/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/slick-carousel@1.8.1/slick/slick.min.js"></script>

<link href="https://kenwheeler.github.io/slick/slick/slick-theme.css" rel="stylesheet"/>
<h1>NETFLIX</h1>
<div class="wrapper">
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-1567-1123.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/412e4119fb212e3ca9f1add558e2e7fed42f8fb4/AAAABRvngexxF8H1-OzRWFSj6ddD-aB93tTBP9kMNz3cIVfuIfLEP1E_0saiNAwOtrM6xSOXvoiSCMsihWSkW0dq808-R7_lBnr6WHbjkKBX6I3sD0uCcS8kSPbRjEDdG8CeeVXEAEV6spQ.webp" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/412e4119fb212e3ca9f1add558e2e7fed42f8fb4/AAAABZEK-7pZ1H5FD4cTyUb9qB_KeyJGz5p-kfPhCFv4GU_3mbdm8Xfsy4IBchlG9PFNdGff8cBNPaeMra72VFnot41nt0y3e8RLgaVwwh3UvyM2H2_MkmadWbQUeGuf811K7-cxJJh7gA.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/412e4119fb212e3ca9f1add558e2e7fed42f8fb4/AAAABQCoK53qihwVPLRxPEDX98nyYpGbxgi5cc0ZOM4iHQu7KQvtgNyaNM5PsgI0vy5g3rLPZdjGCFr1EggrCPXpL77p2H08jV0tNEmIfs_e8KUfvBJ6Ay5nM4UM1dl-58xA6t1swmautOM.webp" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/412e4119fb212e3ca9f1add558e2e7fed42f8fb4/AAAABdYtAqj8CyaJTWq5taD8Ro_UgwH3nne9QpFGVps-2J3IG-leqrfqXFii4jzZn48nPYTkrlwKQEV0R7_cEKlYBPRzdKqNODc-Oz26IL3LlLgFboXibIWXwxzeYxzuqn0I9TpARjeByw.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/412e4119fb212e3ca9f1add558e2e7fed42f8fb4/AAAABbcCX42tsqGbBvO2y9CQv5-7QvYbCfoHtXsuc6NPCtZaKa4l4fBX3XWvUwG9F2A3CTsNpHVmulxBbdXKwK8Q6xGjejd9FoadGkZ7CnGrSl601TOQjzSHJ23NuIPC8j0QMGORL4uRIA.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/412e4119fb212e3ca9f1add558e2e7fed42f8fb4/AAAABVopDZ5Fy9_fk_HO5WxHTXKKjKhtWFupbSjuvPwfLK_vytzon4EwRUdGgYJ34JwPxOTK_NkV3aXfkULMB0Dcct-FyfqzH-X44VXuRMp4QeBHlvKwWeZFpZlGdItPzmmg4scmwhG7SQ.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/412e4119fb212e3ca9f1add558e2e7fed42f8fb4/AAAABTOj1-116yVcgKWMU2dI3GFR4x0fSkiGsqtLLeLUxRR7STaksjAqBTrYlTfrB8nIGnGvXksi0ewXAhVGg6-pLxpFOIfcpjK-pf8D5xehFZo5a6vJbo4L0AGbrzglbyUoq255QBJgRQ.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/a76057bcfd003711a76fb3985b1f2cf74beee3b8/AAAABd3IBDpxbRcHXvRMFCZeKa2aHLU1P4SJtrACMS9om3yhLjqPlvNlmR_fypPxjtbsbnKaC4JZhPSpDG4r_kdxSHHAltWguMcCB-1Y1OShr2zWfUv7Whf_39fNH5ZJ3_0gxQrs0akmQjQz44_LT7jXH5LMZ7iMBAzac5IEj4m7Fn_5OWEGYnVsDsKG-QTommDooULMDF9bEw.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/a76057bcfd003711a76fb3985b1f2cf74beee3b8/AAAABXSd7bhDddcwkq9XpksoQFCHVx29Sxl_h4hb2n3F2GIt32a4XWcOnctQfgnT5qdolv8UML6_xNB5CJ89h56wueb13mYmEBr0sx5e9iLPdtVcOQAOmKXKWHHXwFvJuCUwuNnL3s8eAQwqLXPVMHMEsujM684rUGrZNF2btN2GRy5-RyEslsxZO93V2Q_H2bWs8A8oayt1h5M.webp" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/a76057bcfd003711a76fb3985b1f2cf74beee3b8/AAAABbXWODpAWqVXcmmjMA7K-2mPkQpvwCLfSdeyhVXzR8A3MSpdSEnnjf4HEJJTYC-TnktU6njTUGAxmzWEYCaJbk4v_ZeL-7QGzmkvYBjg_N-evr2XmcX-Fanoyvu_nimFP4iigPe4O3Vr_WcgplhwkDrJwPUJa84wRLrNAx3TufN5V7cWRP4indqu5HQahvgFEqfL9zjp4g.jpg" />
  </div>

  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/412e4119fb212e3ca9f1add558e2e7fed42f8fb4/AAAABRr4YxdaABuAuH_3FmSQZn7BCvLp-UUPsXE9MiYpvFP3CSUHV2zOew5oVqKqqdaOd3tbFVS0Uf67uIs7_eZydlCghg4nK0nMatRpPImABwTOhnNzCLCxdKrua7pPIcPCZqBYTeAO5g.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/412e4119fb212e3ca9f1add558e2e7fed42f8fb4/AAAABTyWK1MKaw8GcObtz47R2Tj7wkLJ7qQu9tk6TVpcoyxpzD4B-zZ569bQ5vGrREBL-MWFkGilXUwy7tCDaj2XOGkUB4RsbbFAmp9NgSr6lygMpUGNHSlyfrFbUORsRkrxSIoh_ggOvg.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/a76057bcfd003711a76fb3985b1f2cf74beee3b8/AAAABY7NwkWEJIfXsn6t3Li4bGSCQ1nEErPisI5ZZtXlC-_VRBZOUrhWK5X3vt3t6SR_cpgVhCwxgQqFFDJhk62Kk8hawOnYGZMr0LKeLczMFV2zalCFjkcdLksvT4HB2LEi6LFyruyk3Uu0LmNGsHfC2A8Bly60smr_3sDbz4RruXcklPOG1qYq9wUVu3zfaiwNvqmG4b8aFA.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/a76057bcfd003711a76fb3985b1f2cf74beee3b8/AAAABemXHOga9feFnOux6I2YyACBD94wvM7N3vcTGIfMpQ_BcaXeoeM9XyzdVdamKtxt0SHXZfvsl6czcp3E48tXMLtHBxuQsh1BjHtPGgJDZ81je_FjItINiqzLtir0A30s_e4KR8G3d7AYAPDjZVOY97bNpzNqtkcHcGp7fGnJByVCps1uLfG9U9tK3Ma1A_3JbRt0NiT2_Q.jpg" />
  </div>
  <div class="item">
    <img src="https://occ-0-243-299.1.nflxso.net/dnm/api/v5/rendition/a76057bcfd003711a76fb3985b1f2cf74beee3b8/AAAABVxuRB932hvre-XP0gh6ar5ztoR3Oe3QjKHkyvcDnRak2MKXOrx5H7mFQSvggefMFOppwEs7ZCCpiqrJ_CYGvtvYB9NpU4SWUtNO6uV2u-DTID267AcHjHcGvGBQJ1ufddDkxcGOZyi5MlOQ5QUmBun4652FbYUnib3zMYQDgcna_Pvz8y_HO5fbokxezrRR1JZAAiqFSQ.jpg" />
  </div>

</div>
```

Comment: bro everything is fine but the next and previous button are below the images when i copied this code into sublime.

Comment: did you missed to add the two css files ??

Comment: bro its working actually i was in hurry and i missed that lol

Comment: thanks again bro .. i think its second time answered my question.. Have a good day6